# ViemAdapter for @safe-global/protocol-kit?

Tags: gnosis-safe, web3auth, viem

I was trying to use `@safe-global` modules but found that in the protocol kit, only Ethers.js (<v6) and Web3.js are supported. I tend to use Viem and Wagmi because of their advantages in development. Is there any `ViemAdapter` for `@safe-global` in development or released by someone else?

Ideal scenario would be to be able to use Viem with its advantages with `@safe-global` SDK and the `Web3AuthModalPack`. Open to contribute to the safe if needed.

Comment: In theory there is no issue with having a `ViemAdapter` included in the Safe{Core} SDK, but there is currently no short-term plan to implement it as the team has other priorities at this moment. Of course, feel free to contribut to the repo if you like, we would appreciate that a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I've started an unofficial Safe library for Viem, maybe it helps in your case:

https://piggybank.stauro.xyz

Here's an example:

```js
import { http, createPublicClient, parseEther, createWalletClient, Hex } from 'viem'
import { goerli } from 'viem/chains'
import { publicSafeActions, walletSafeActions } from '@stauro/piggybank/actions'
import { EIP3770Address, OperationType } from '@stauro/piggybank/types'
import { ApiClient } from '@stauro/piggybank/api'
import { privateKeyToAccount } from 'viem/accounts'

const safeAddress = process.env.SAFE_ADDRESS as EIP3770Address

const publicClient = createPublicClient({
  transport: http(),
  chain: goerli,
}).extend(publicSafeActions(safeAddress))

const walletClient = createWalletClient({
  transport: http(),
  chain: goerli,
  account: privateKeyToAccount(process.env.PK as Hex),
}).extend(walletSafeActions(safeAddress))

const txData = {
  to: process.env.SAFE_TO as EIP3770Address,
  value: parseEther('0.001'),
  operation: OperationType.Call,
  gasPrice: await publicClient.getGasPrice(),
}

const safeTxGas = await publicClient.estimateSafeTransactionGas(txData)

const baseGas = await publicClient.estimateSafeTransactionBaseGas({ ...txData, safeTxGas })

const nonce = await publicClient.getSafeNonce()

const safeTxHash = await publicClient.getSafeTransactionHash({ ...txData, safeTxGas, baseGas, nonce })

const senderSignature = await walletClient.generateSafeTransactionSignature({ ...txData, nonce, safeTxGas, baseGas })

const apiClient = new ApiClient({ url: 'https://safe-transaction-goerli.safe.global', safeAddress })

await apiClient.proposeTransaction({
  safeTransactionData: { ...txData, safeTxGas, baseGas, nonce },
  senderAddress: walletClient.account.address,
  safeTxHash,
  senderSignature,
  chainId: goerli.id,
  origin: 'Piggybank',
  nonce,
})
```

for now only transaction proposal works but I'm glad to add any other APIs.